# msys2 network performance woes

Tags: networking, ssh, wget, scp

With a fresh install of msys2 32-bit (needed for git-annex) from https://msys2.github.io/ on Windows 7 SP1 64-bit, I'm seeing incredibly slow network transfer speeds on wget, ssh, rsync, etc. For example, if I download a file using Chrome, I get 5MB/s. With wget, I'm capped at 1MB/s. If I try wget from msys2 64-bit, I get 2MB/s. Similarly, scp using a linux machine on the same network is 8MB/s, while scp from msys2 stays at 1MB/s.

Wireshark captures of the two transfers shows identical packets with the exception that the TCP window size is different.

I don't know enough about how Windows networking and msys2's use of it is set up to even start troubleshooting; would appreciate any ideas. Searching for "msys2 network/ssh/wget/tcp performance" isn't yielding any results.

Thanks!